# Getting vote counts for a Post using Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

Here's my database schema:

```
create table Post
(
    PostId int primary key identity,
    ImageUrl nvarchar(1024) not null,
    [Description] nvarchar(256) not null,
    UserId int foreign key references [User](UserId),
    DateOfPost datetime not null,
    Score int
)

create table Vote
(
    VoteId int primary key identity,
    UserId int foreign key references [User](UserId),
    PostId int foreign key references Post(PostId),
    VoteDirection bit not null,
    DateOfVote datetime not null
)
```

Basically, I want to order the Posts by `[VoteDirection == true] - [VoteDirection == false]`. So it 20 people votes "true", and 5 vote "false", the temporary score used for ordering would be 15.

Is there also a way to select a range of date using the DateOfVote parameter?

Here's what I've tried:

```
    // www.foo.com/top/today
    public ActionResult Today()
    {
        var posts = postRepository.FindAllPosts().Where(x => x.DateOfPost == DateTime.Today)
                                                 .OrderByDescending(x => x.Votes.Where(c => c.VoteDirection == true) - x.Votes.Where(c => c.VoteDirection == false));
        return View(posts);
    }
```

I'm getting the error:

> Error 2   Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'
>   and
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

Which is understandable, they're both collections not actual integers. But it should illustrate what I'm trying to do. Any suggestions?

Comment: `.Where()` returns an `IQueryable`, not a numeric value, so you can't just subtract the two results.  @dbaseman's answer is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `Count`:

```
.OrderByDescending(x => 
    x.Votes.Count(c => c.VoteDirection) - x.Votes.Count(c => !c.VoteDirection));
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: `Error 3 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<EstoEsBolivia.Domain.Vote>' does not contain a definition for 'Sum' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Sum(System.Linq.IQueryable<int>)' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: @Serg sorry about that, I meant to say `Count`, not Sum.

Comment: Yeah I wanted to edit my comment to say that. Count works just fine. Thanks for the help!